Record video playing in canvas with full volume even if it is playing on lower volume
Hello and thank you for your time,
I am recording a video which is mirror-playing in a canvas from that canvas.
The original video is seated in a normal  tag.
When recording the volume of the recorded video is the same as set in the original video- element playing at that moment, in this case 0.1 which is 10%.
When I adjust the volume while recording I can hear this volume changing in the recording.
What I want is that the recorded video gets the full possible volume of the original video so I can play the recorded video with the exact same maximum volume.
Trying to set the connected gainNode to maximum volume did not succed because the result is fraked, like it is totally overvolumed, like cracking speakers.
gain_node.gain.value = gain_node.gain.maxValue;
The gainNode- object has this maxValue set: 3.4028234663852886e+38
The usual gain- value is 1 as is in the listener, too.
Is there a posibility to record the video with the highest volume of the original video?

Please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks!

Why do you go through the web audio API?

I do so because on my first tries I did not catch any audio in the recording so I thought I were supposed to use the Audio API to record the audio played i the video, too.
